# Is there a VSCode shortcut or command similar to VIM for grepping lines?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Sometimes I need to look for lines that do not contain a string. For example, on our Jenkins files, there's a lot of "Downloading $package". I can copy the file into VIM and do a `:g/Downloading/d` and all lines that contain the word "Downloading" will be deleted.

Is there something like that in VSCode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install the vscodevim and enable the Neovim setting(below), you will be able to use :g functionality.

"vim.enableNeovim": true

Answer (score 0):

VS Code supports regexp in find, and it even supports a kind of inverse matching.

In your case you can enable regexp in the "Find..." box (the button with the ".*" symbol) and use `^((?!Downloading).)*$` to match all lines that do not contain the string "Downloading".

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to find the lines, I want them removed out of my doc.

Comment: You have to think with the philosophy of the tool that you're using. You can use the regexp I wrote, use "Find all" and remove them. Once you found them all you could even set a cursor at each line and modify all of them simultaneously. Different tool, different methods, but in the end what matters is whatever works for you.